# How can I put one or multiple echo inside other echo?

Tags: php, string, echo

I have this line:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[accordion id="delivery"] [accordion_item title="Delivery" parent_id="delivery"] XYZ [/accordion_item] [/accordion]'); ?>
```

And I need to put below code instead of XYZ in above code:

```
<br></br><i class="x-icon-truck" data-x-icon-s="&#xf0d1;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'delivery_date_morroco', true ); ?>
```

Could you please guide me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: without any other information about those functions above, guide: "copy paste", "concat in php" and probably if needed "escape character"

Comment: put the post meta inside the variable, then concatenate the variable in the shortcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with a single echo if you do it the following way.

We're declaring variables and using string concatenation.

```
<?php
  $truck_icon = "<br></br><i class=\"x-icon-truck\" data-x-icon-s=\"&#xf0d1;\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>";
  $post_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'delivery_date_morroco', true );
  
  echo do_shortcode('[accordion id="delivery"] [accordion_item title="Delivery" parent_id="delivery"]' . $truck_icon . $post_meta . '[/accordion_item] [/accordion]'); ?>
```

Comment: does it have to be stored into a variable? can we do it in 1 long string?
`<?php echo do_shortcode('[accordion id="delivery"] [accordion_item title="Delivery" parent_id="delivery"] <br></br><i class="x-icon-truck" data-x-icon-s="&#xf0d1;" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'delivery_date_morroco', true ) . '[/accordion_item] [/accordion]'); ?>`

Comment: We totally can do it in 1 long string, I used variables to improve readability and hopefully make the solution less confusing.

Comment: @camaulay I noticed T_Variable syntax error for $post_meta = ....

Comment: @BoykeFerdinandes Thanks,Your code works but I am looking to do it in a manner which camaulay has done.

Comment: @OmidToraby thanks for noticing that error, i've updated my post - i think it's because I missed the semi-colon at the end.